# How to limit FPS in a loop with C++?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I'm trying to limit the frames per second in a loop that is performing intersection checking, using C++ with chrono and thread.

Here is my code:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point lastFrame = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

while (true)
{
    // Maintain designated frequency of 5 Hz (200 ms per frame)
    now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> delta = now - lastFrame;
    lastFrame = now;

    if (delta.count() < 200.0)
    {
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> delta_ms(200.0 - delta.count());
        auto delta_ms_duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(delta_ms);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delta_ms_duration.count()));
    }

    printf("Time: %f \n", delta.count());

    // Perform intersection test

}
```

The problem I'm having is that every other output of delta is showing miniscule amounts, rather than the ~200 ms / frame I'm aiming for:

```
Time: 199.253200
Time: 2.067700
Time: 199.420400
Time: 2.408100
Time: 199.494200
Time: 2.306200
Time: 199.586800
Time: 2.253400
Time: 199.864000
Time: 2.156500
Time: 199.293800
Time: 2.075500
Time: 201.787500
Time: 4.426600
Time: 197.304100
Time: 4.530500
Time: 198.457200
Time: 3.482000
Time: 198.365300
Time: 3.415400
Time: 198.467400
Time: 3.595000
Time: 199.730100
Time: 3.373400
```

Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Comment: Your times seem to be aproximately 200ms, so what's the problem? You can't expect to get anything near exact timings.. you get a little less than 200, then you get a tiny bit more, deal with it - you are not going to ever get exactly 200 every time.

Comment: I'm not aiming for exact timings, but I don't understand why some loop iterations are 1-4 ms and others are ~200 ms.

Comment: because sometimes your deltacount < 200 and you still output it

Comment: The OS may schedule your program whenever it likes - one reason. You may be doing something silly somewhere, like sleeping for some amount of time..

Comment: @strangeqargo delta should include the sleep time of the previous iteration (except for the first iteration of course) so I think it should be around 200ms.

Comment: @Irongrave Not an answer but the way you're code is organized is slightly confusing. You should get the time, do calculations, get the time again and then sleep for the difference. I think you're doing that here but the loop starts at a weird point.

Comment: Assuming that due to precision of all your sleeps last shorter than expected, you first sleep for 198ms, so delta is ~198ms, so sleep for ~2ms, so your delta is ~2ms.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am sleeping in the loop above to attempt to maintain the 5 fps frame rate, I assume you mean aside from that.  Aside from that, there is nowhere else in my program I am sleeping, and I'm not using any crazy libraries, either -- just iostream, cmath, chrono and thread.

Comment: You should sleep after intersection test, to target the 200ms.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you think about how your code works, you'll find out that it works exactly how you wrote it. Delta oscillates because of a logical mistake in the code.

This is what happens:

- We start with `delta == 0`.
- Because the delta is smaller than `200`, you code sleeps `200 - delta(0) == 200` ms.
- Now, the delta itself becomes close to `200` (because you've measured that sleep time as well as an actual work) and you sleep `200 - delta(200) == 0` ms.
- After that the cycle repeats.

To fix the problem you need to not measure the sleep time.

This is how it can be done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point a = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point b = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Maintain designated frequency of 5 Hz (200 ms per frame)
        a = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> work_time = a - b;

        if (work_time.count() < 200.0)
        {
            std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> delta_ms(200.0 - work_time.count());
            auto delta_ms_duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(delta_ms);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delta_ms_duration.count()));
        }

        b = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> sleep_time = b - a;

        // Your code here

        printf("Time: %f \n", (work_time + sleep_time).count());
    }
}
```

This code gives me a steady sequence of deltas:

```
Time: 199.057206 
Time: 199.053581 
Time: 199.064718 
Time: 199.053515 
Time: 199.053307 
Time: 199.053415 
Time: 199.053164 
Time: 199.053511 
Time: 199.053280 
Time: 199.053283
```

Comment: Great explanation, I see where I went wrong now.  Thank you.

Comment: the conversation inside sleep_fo()r is not requidred , proof : 

static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(std::chrono::milliseconds()),decltype(delta_ms_duration)>(),"");
 does not fail ,

Comment: But this code calls the system clock two times per loop, which is inefficient.

Answer (score 17):

This is much like [Galik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38730986/576911), but it keeps the syntax of the OP's question and doesn't drop down to the C API.  Additionally it creates a custom unit for the frame duration which I believe is important for readability:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    using frames = duration<int64_t, ratio<1, 5>>;  // 5Hz
    auto nextFrame = system_clock::now();
    auto lastFrame = nextFrame - frames{1};;

    while (true)
    {
        // Perform intersection test

        this_thread::sleep_until(nextFrame);
        cout << "Time: "  // just for monitoring purposes
             << duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now() - lastFrame).count()
             << "ms\n";
        lastFrame = nextFrame;
        nextFrame += frames{1};
    }
}
```

This outputs for me:

```
Time: 200ms
Time: 205ms
Time: 205ms
Time: 203ms
Time: 205ms
Time: 205ms
Time: 200ms
Time: 200ms
Time: 200ms
...
```

Key things to note:

- A concise way to document 5Hz: `using frames = duration<int64_t, ratio<1, 5>>;`
- Use of `sleep_until` instead of `sleep_for`, which takes care of the unknown of how long it takes to get the real work done.
- No use of `.count()` except for I/O, and [here's a library to get rid of that](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/chrono_io.html).
- No manual conversion of units (e.g. `/ 1000`).
- No floating point units, not that there's anything wrong with that.
- Minimal need to specify or depend upon explicit units.

With the addition of the [duration I/O library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/chrono_io.html),  here is how the above code would be changed:

```
#include "chrono_io.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    using frames = duration<int64_t, ratio<1, 5>>;  // 5Hz
    auto nextFrame = system_clock::now();
    auto lastFrame = nextFrame - frames{1};;

    while (true)
    {
        // Perform intersection test

        this_thread::sleep_until(nextFrame);
        // just for monitoring purposes
        cout << "Time: " << system_clock::now() - lastFrame << '\n';
        lastFrame = nextFrame;
        nextFrame += frames{1};
    }
}
```

The output would differ depending upon platform (depending upon the "native duration" of `system_clock`).  On my platform it looks like this:

```
Time: 200042µs
Time: 205105µs
Time: 205107µs
Time: 200044µs
Time: 205105µs
Time: 200120µs
Time: 204307µs
Time: 205136µs
Time: 201978µs
...
```

Comment: I get compile errors (both with VS 2017 and GCC 7) when I change the ratio to be 30 ot 60 Hz - ```error C2679: binary '+=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'frames' (or there is no acceptable conversion)``` - any idea why?

Comment: Yes, this is the compiler warning you that you have a truncation error when adding 1/30 of a second (for example) to a `system_clock::time_point` because `system_clock::time_point` can't exactly represent 1/30 of a second.  But this is easy to fix!  Just add `frames{0}` to system_clock::now() and let `auto` do its magic: `auto nextFrame = system_clock::now() + frames{0};`.  Now instead of trafficking in `system_clock::time_point`, you're using a time_point that can exactly represent the sum of frames and system_clock::time_point precision.

Answer (score 15):

I usualy do something like this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;

    auto next_frame = clock::now();

    while(true)
    {
        next_frame += std::chrono::milliseconds(1000 / 5); // 5Hz

        // do stuff
        std::cout << std::time(0) << '\n'; // 5 for each second

        // wait for end of frame
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(next_frame);
    }
}
```

**Output:** (five for each second value)

```
1470173964
1470173964
1470173964
1470173964
1470173964
1470173965
1470173965
1470173965
1470173965
1470173965
1470173966
1470173966
1470173966
1470173966
1470173966
```

Comment: This is my favorite, except that I would define a custom `frame` unit:  `using frames = std::chrono::duration<std::int64_t, std::ratio<1, 5>>;`, and then do `next_from += frames{1};`.  That keeps manual conversions out of the code.

Comment: solution missing
#include <thread>

Comment: I can run the solution without #include <ctime>

Comment: @OneArb Yes, but the C++ Standard doesn't guarantee that. So it's needed to be portable.

Answer (score 4):

The alternating delta times are arising from a logic problem: you're adding a delay to one frame based on the duration of the frame before (in terms of how the frame durations are reckoned).  This means that after a long frame (~200ms) you don't apply a delay and get a short frame (few ms), which then triggers a delay on the next frame giving a long frame, and so on.