# C++ Camera Simulation

Tags: c++, opencv, timer, sleep

I am currently working on grabbing camera image by opencv in C++,

the current blocker is the time clock issue.

I am wondering how I should make thread to sleep to make the FPS correct.

My current solution is to use nanosleep.

This is my code when FPS is set to 50Hz.

```
for(;;)
    {
        clock_t trueStart = clock();
        cap >> frame;
        if( frame.empty() ) break; // end of video stream
        if( waitKey(10) == 27 ) break; // stop capturing by pressing ESC
        uint8_t* pixelPtr = frame.data;
        int cn = frame.channels();
        // wait until the next frame becomes 1.
        while (!data[currentFrame] == 0){
        }
        memcpy(data, pixelPtr, (size_t) frameByteSize);
        data[currentFrame] = 0;
        currentFrame = currentFrame % maximumFrames;
        clock_t end = clock();
        double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
//        for(int i = 0; i < frame.rows; i++)
//        {
//            for(int j = 0; j < frame.cols; j++)
//            {
//                data[0] = pixelPtr[i*frame.cols*cn + j*cn + 0]; // B
//                data[1] = pixelPtr[i*frame.cols*cn + j*cn + 1]; // G
//                data[2] = pixelPtr[i*frame.cols*cn + j*cn + 2]; // R
//                // do something with BGR values...
//                exit(0);
//            }
//        }
        //videoWriter.write(frame);
        double waitTime = 1.0 / frameRate - elapsed_secs;
        int endwait;
        endwait = clock() + waitTime * CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;
        while (clock() < endwait){}

        nanosleep((const struct timespec[]){{0, ((long) waitTime) * 1000000000L}}, NULL);
        clock_t trueEnd = clock();
        double elapsed = double(trueEnd - trueStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        cout << elapsed << endl;
        begin = clock();

    }
```

However, the output was not good:

```
0.022796
0.020024
0.020011
0.020034
0.020041
0.020024
0.023907
0.020443
0.020027
0.020019
0.020024
0.020011
0.020049
0.020011
0.020032
0.020022
0.020025
0.020097
0.022034
```

I am wondering is there any better to do this?

Comment: [std::this_thread::sleep_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) may help you.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl Thanks! does that provide higher accuracy?

Comment: This answer may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38730273/how-to-limit-fps-in-a-loop-with-c/38730986#38730986

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39987806/accurate-sampling-in-c/39988284#39988284

Comment: Doesn't your camera provide some means of setting a fixed frame rate? (perhaps by setting the `CV_CAP_PROP_FPS` property) (or maybe I misunderstood and you're reading from a file -- that bit is missing, although the title hints at the possibility).

Comment: OK, after reading a bit more into this, it seems to me that the issue is that you only time things relative to the start of each iteration and never compensate for taking too long by, for example, making the next wait shorter. You need to time everything relative to a fixed "origin" time. Say you start at time `T`, then you know that the second frame needs to happen at `T+20ms`, third at `T+40ms`, ...